# Use master instead of main for git

Tags: git, github

I just made a new git repo and pushed it to github, but noticed my git commands aren't working because git show-ref shows only 'main' instead of 'master'. I want to use master since that's what all my commands and tools expect. How can I change it to use 'master' instead of 'main'?

Comment: Just change the branch name. But of course you'll need to do something about the remote. See https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Comment: `~ $ git config --global init.defaultBranch master` to make it always use master instead main

Comment: Better adopt the tools to be able to work with `main` instead. A shift towards `main` has happened because `master` is offensive to some.

Comment: Is there some evidence that master in context of git branches is offensive to some? I mean, I get that it might be offensive in database replication or other context when there's a master and a slave but in this case there is no slave. Why is that an offensive term? I complain because I have to switch between a lot of repos that use both and having to remember which is which is annoying and a waste of time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please try the following steps:

step 1) check your local branch also named 'main'. You can check that in your local repository by:

```
git branch
```

If it is 'main', after making both remote and local up-to-date, rename your local 'main' branch to  'master' and push the branch to remote. If the local repo is already 'master', skip renaming the branch and directly push. Make sure no 'master' branch exist currently in the remote repo. If yes, delete or rename that before pushing.

```
git branch -m main master
git push -u origin master
```

step 2) Log in to your remote repo, and change the default branch to master. You can refer to this, in case you have any trouble doing that:

https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch

Step 3) Delete the 'main' branch in the remote repo. You can do it from the browser.

https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/creating-and-deleting-branches-within-your-repository

Or you can do the following commands:

```
git push origin --delete main
git remote set-head origin -a
```

I think this will help. Also, requesting you to check why Github has decided to change from 'master' to 'main', if possible.

Reference : https://dev.to/rhymu/git-renaming-the-master-branch-137b